# How do I get a list of all computed properties?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Using ember data, I've run across an issue during serialization where computed properties are not included in the payload.

```
var Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:  DS.attr('string'),
    fullName:  function( ) {
            return this.firstName + this.lastName;
    }.property()
});

App.store.createRecord( Person, {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName:  'Doe'
});
App.store.commit();
```

Results in the following payload:

```
{ firstName: "John",
  lastName:  "Doe" }
```

I've tried adding `.cacheable()` to the property, but it didn't seem to help. I've also tried wrapping the entire `fullName` function in `Ember.computed()`, but that didn't seem to help, either.

Tracing the Ember code, I see that the data for the request comes from `DS.Model.serialize()` which collects all the attributes for the model. However, it does not seem to collect computed properties.

Ember Code Snippet:

```
serialize: function(record, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var serialized = this.createSerializedForm(), id;

  if (options.includeId) {
    if (id = get(record, 'id')) {
      this._addId(serialized, record.constructor, id);
    }
  }

  this.addAttributes(serialized, record);
  this.addRelationships(serialized, record);

  return serialized;
},

addAttributes: function(data, record) {
  record.eachAttribute(function(name, attribute) {
    this._addAttribute(data, record, name, attribute.type);
  }, this);
}
```

As you can see, they collect attributes and relationships, but there doesn't seem to be anything collecting computed properties. My strategy at first was to overload `addAttributes()` to also loop through all computed properties and add them to the list. But in my attempt, couldn't figure out a reliable way to get a list of computed properties. If I made the properties cacheable, I could use `Ember.meta( model, 'cache' )` but that list includes all attributes, computed properties, and a few extras that I don't need/want.

So, my questions after all of this...

- Is there a way in Ember that already exists to cause computed properties to be included in the serialization?
- If not, I can overload appropriate methods, but how do I get a dynamic list of all computed properties? (I can use `.getProperties()` but it expects an array of property names, which I don't have)
- Any other relevant suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it, but does [eachComputedProperty](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_eachComputedProperty) suit your purposes?

Comment: That must be relatively new, cuz I don't have that method in my copy. It's only been a week or so, but I will be sure to get a new copy of -latest and let you know, ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. It appears `eachComputedProperty` does exist in my copy, but for some reason is not available on an instance of `DS.Model`. According to the code, DS.Model extends Ember.Object, so it should be there, but it's not. Looking into why now.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing, but [from what I can see here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js) DS.Store does not extend Ember.Object. Seems crazy so I am questioning if I am really looking at the right thing.

Comment: No, I said `DS.Model` extends `Ember.Object`. But using `DS.Model.createRecord()` is just a wrapper to `DS.Store.createRecord` which returns a record object which does not have a `eachComputedProperty` method :(

Comment: Coming back to this question after 2.5 months, I now realize my original question is just a stupid one. In any other case, this would likely have been the proper solution.